# execute jquery below a certain viewport width

Tags: jquery, media-queries

hi folks i've found a few answers on this but can't seem to get any of them working . i've got a typical responsive nav that changes to a menu icon below a certain viewport width . i have the anchor tags in the dropdown menu close the menu when clicked as they are executing a scroll to function. however this is not useful when above a certain width . here's my code . i think this may be the way to go but suspect that my syntax is incorrect

```
<script> 
    if($(window).width() <= 900){
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $(".trigger , .close").click(function(){
           $(".showing ").slideToggle("slow");
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, reverse the order of the `width()` and `ready()` lines. Then use the `.add()` to apply the click to both buttons (`$(".trigger, .close")` should work, but I think `.add()` is cleaner)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 900){         
        $(".trigger").add(".close").click(function(){
            $(".showing ").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jm5okh69/6/

(note that $(document).ready() isn't included.

Comment: Annnd I broke my answer trying out your code. One moment.

Comment: thanks for the reply . it's a weird one this . clearly your fiddle works yet when i add it into my script the trigger and close classes no longer toggle the menu

Comment: It's probably something stupid. You forgot a period somewhere? A pound sign? Put up more of the code, if possible and I'd be happy to have a look (within reason).

Comment: found another way of doing it where the jquery is triggered by a media query . e.g if a fontsize for example is changed below a certain viewport width that media query is used to trigger the jquery . seems to be a much cleaner way to do it as opposed to using window width as there seem to be some inconsistencies between browsers . thanks for the help . hope this is useful if you need to do something similar

Comment: I think some browsers will interpret the vertical scrollbar as part of the width and some don't--meaning they can all disagree by about 20px. But you can force a scrollbar with css--and I often do if I'm going to have content that can't fill one window.

I'm not sure, but I think basing layout on front size is a bad idea. You can't (and don't want) to control the user's experience like that. I'm still not clear what your issue is, but I wouldn't base javascript behavior on font size.

Comment: the font size is just an example . it can be anything that changes at the media query width you wish your script to start running . say before the media query a  div has float left and inside the media query it has float none  -   $(document).ready(function() {
                 checkSize();
              $(window).resize(checkSize);
});

function checkSize(){
    if ($(".sampleClass").css("float") == "none" ){
        // js here
    }
}

Comment: I still don't understand the specifics, but .outerWidth() will report an elements "true" width, that is with padding and margins included. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: after doing more research it seems that firing jquery using media queries as opposed to window width is the more consistent and fool proof way to go . here's one such article . https://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries